# Can "either that" be appended at the end of a sentence with a comma?

Tags: punctuation

Example:

> She was an antisocial person, either that or she was a sociopath.

As opposed to:

> She was an antisocial person. Either that or she was a sociopath.

Is the first case grammatical? Why or why not?

Comment: The question is about the most appropriate pause after **person**. The construction works with a comma. I should prefer a semi-colon. it doesn't work with a full stop (period) because the second half is not an independent sentence.

Comment: I think by all normal standards, the comma version isn't valid orthography.

Comment: Neither version looks 100% grammatical by strict rules, but both of them look fine as a reflection of how people actually speak.  To me, the version with a comma sounds like a shorter pause than the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one sounds natural for either speaking or writing, with a comma added like this.

"She was an antisocial person. Either that, or she was a sociopath."

The first one sounds natural in a casual spoken conversation, but would look too casual in something like a book.